# How to compute sum of 'x' numbers starting from 'y'

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, given numbers x=3 and y=4, the result should be sum of 
`(4 + 0) + (4 + 1) + (4 + 2)` = 15

As another example, given numbers x = 4, and y = 8. the result should be sum of
`(8 + 0) + (8 + 1) + (8 + 2) + (8 + 3)` = 38

I am looking for furmula similar to somthing like `n(n+1)/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=y}^{y+x-1}k=\sum_{k=0}^{y+x-1}k-\sum_{k=0}^{y-1}k$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\left(y+k\right)=xy+\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}k=xy+\frac{1}{2}x\left(x-1\right)$$